# Can we extend a existing polymer element without touching the original code?

Tags: polymer, web-component

The current `core-header-panel` element's `mode="waterfall-tall"` doesn't fully support `core-toolbar` title and summary. Which mean when user scrolling the title and summary will overlap so I want to extend something here to hide the summary when scrolling.

Can we do that with extending the `core-header-panel` but don't need to touch the original code?
If so, how to do that and any tutorial around?

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you mean by overlapping title and summary?

Comment: Hi Rob, i do know how to do after checking out the core-header-panel demos also i'm weezhen at twitter (the orc profile picture). Btw, it is difficult to understand webcomponent which from angular background. Do you have any useful guide for beginner?

Comment: I would recommend you read all of Eric's articles on HTML5 Rocks. Then Polymer (and Web Components) will make more sense.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Answer (score 0):

one way to alter the elements with touching the the original code is to add `/deep/` to the CSS selector.

eg:

```
core-header-panel /deep/ selector
 {
  background-color: #E60000; 
 }
```